What determines the farthest options date of a stock?
Most stocks have options open up to 1 yr into the future and some even up to 2yrs. However, I see one stock (IAS) which has two monthly dates followed by two quarterly dates (in 2025). What factors determine options of a stock to be available for a shorter or longer duration?

There are 3 expiration cycles:

January, April, July, October

February, May, August, November

March, June, September, December


All optionable stocks offer options in the current month, the following month and at least the next two months in the cycle.
500+ stocks and 100+ ETFs offer weekly options for the next 6 weeks.
Many optionable stocks offer LEAPS (long term options expiring in more than one year) resulting in two subsequent January expirations.
Stocks and ETFs whose options are heavily traded may have even more expiration months.
For example, the most heavily traded options are on the SPY which breaks all of the rules. Its expirations include:

16 midweek and weekly expirations
8 monthly expirations
3 end of month quarterly expirations
7 LEAPs expiring in various months

The short answer is that the greater the interest that traders have, the more months and the more strike prices that will be available to trade.
Here is the CBOE explanation of the option cycles.
Here is the CBOE directory of weekly options
